# memory management for updating dynamic texts

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, memory-management, adobe

what's better for memory and process?
1- one dynamic text and update it each second with:

```
this.t1.text = "Time: " + String(tin);
```

2- or have one static text and one dynamic text that updates with:

```
this.t1.text = String(tin);
```

Comment: When adding strings you should use the String.Concat() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory usage is more important than file size.
Don't worry about increasing file size for increasing performance. That's right decision.
I mean, the second one is better. Yeah, needs a little more work but it's good.

And an important point for that. If you're not using any imported text renderer class, you don't need to use something like that for a text have a few characters like "Time: ", but if you're using long texts, it's better use another text object for dynamic parts of text file even you're using anyother renderer or you're using flash's text input stuff.

I mean, "text's font size" may be important for rendering text elements because of pixel count.